# jQuery concatenate question

Tags: jquery, concatenation

Ok.

html:

```
<div class="selector">
    <select name="something"> //this is what myVar is referring to.
        <option>stuff</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Say I have var:

```
var myVar = $(".selector").find("[name=something]");
```

And I want to concatenate with option:selected:

```
$(myVar here + " option:selected").change(function(){
    //do something
});
```

I can't seem to make this work.  Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: myVar is the *value*, what does it represent? How can you select by it?

Comment: myVar is the name of the <select> menu item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your edited version you've removed `val()`, so `myVar` is a jQuery object. You can do:

```
myVar.find("option:selected")
```

or better

```
$("option:selected", myVar)
```

Comment: Yea the change event does work for this.  Haven't had a problem with that.  I'm going to edit for more clarity.

Comment: I need to stick with classes...the div "selector" is generated from $.post. And there will be more than one in the code.

Comment: Yea..made mistake..the select menu has no value..sorry.  I've updated the example to show that.

Comment: I like the looks of your last suggestion...I'll try it.  Thanks.

Comment: I it's straight hierarchy, you can also do `$(".selector [name=something] option:selected")` - one selector, no `find`, all classes.

Comment: no problem, was it the answer or the comment? I'll edit the answer to be clearer.

Comment: `$(" option:selected", myVar)` Just wanted to add...that there needs to be a space before `option:selected` in order for it to work correctly. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Leading space? That is... strange. I'll check that later. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @Kobi...it works either way with/without space.  I just tried it.

Comment: Ok, good to know. That sort of things can end in bug reports. Thanks. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

That should work (assuming the word 'here' isn't in the code). What does the the element with name = something contain as a value? what are the elements you expect to get using the jquery method?

Comment: Sorry..err the select menu in the example has no val..edited.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the selector method may not return you only one element, this may be better way to use jQuery.

```
 $("select").change(function () {

          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                // do something
              });

        })
        .trigger('change');
```